Is there any limitation of creating service connections in azure devops? Can we create 100+ service connection in azure devops?
I need to create 100+ service connections will it be possible to create it or is there any limitation for it in azure devops?
Not able to find this answer in documentation.
Not able to find this answer in documentation.
Followed below links for my above question .
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/users/directory-service-limits-restrictions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits

What kinds of service connections will you create?  In Azure DevOps, there is no limit on the number of Service Connections. I have checked the related docs about Microsoft Entra resource limit. The resource limits related to Service Connections(e,g, Service Principal, Managed Identity) in the documentation are much greater than 100. You can create 100+ service connection without issue.

Refer to this doc: Service Connection Rete Limits

There are no per-project limits placed on creating service connections. However, there might be limits, which are imposed through Microsoft Entra ID.

In Azure DevOps, there is no limit on the number of Service Connections.
If your Service Connection is related to Azure Resource(e.g. ARM Service Connection), it will also be subject to resource limits in Azure Microsoft Entra.
I have checked the following docs: Microsoft Entra service limits and restrictions and Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and constraints.
The resource limits related to Service Connections(e,g, Service Principal, Managed Identity) in the documentation are much greater than 100, so you can create 100+ service connections without any problems.
